# Change type of dictionary member

Tags: c#, dictionary

In class, I declare the generic (base class) type of Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, Animal> dict = new Dictionary<string, Animal>();
```

later I add individual animals (they all derive from Animal)

```
dict["cat"] = (Cat) new Cat();
dict["dog"] = (Dog) new Dog();
```

Cat has the property named `tail`. However, when I try to access that member later in IDE, `dict["cat"].tail` is undefined. Because that member resolves to `Animal` still, instead of `Cat` type.

How can I force/change the type of dictionary member, as `dict["cat"].tail` become available in IDE?

p.s. Do I have everytime & everywhere add the type to that variable?  `((Cat)dict["cat"]...`

Comment: Yes, because the dictionary only exposes it as an `Animal`, you need to cast it.

Comment: Cast the `Animal` to `Cat`. You have already  casted a cat to a cat and a dog to a dog which is pretty useless.

Comment: Side Note: `dict["cat"] = (Cat) new Cat();` can just be `dict["cat"] = new Cat();` no cast needed.

Comment: The dictionary elements are `KeyValuePair<string, Animal>`, whose `Value` will be of type `Animal`. If you want to cast to a derived type, you probably don't have the optimal data structure to store this collection in.

Comment: You are casting on the wrong "side", don't cast when adding the `new Cat()` or `new Dog()` to the Dictionary (its redundant, the dictionary already knows what type it is when you add it).  You have to cast when you read it out.  This gets complicated though because how could you know which element is a `Cat()` and which is a `Dog()`...  I think you are starting to see the issue with your design now.

Comment: You can use @St. Pat answer. You can also use pattern matching like:

`if (dict.ContainsKey("cat") && dict["cat"] is Cat cat)
{
 // Dealing with cat :)
}`

Comment: thanks guys, i knew approaches if I create a new variable. However, good points from you. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the property tail of your cat, you have to cast your cat before

```
((Cat) dict['cat']).tail
```

because when you put your cat in your dictionnary, it will be consider as an Animal if you try to access it by your dictionnary, and your Animal class doesn't have this property while the Cat class does

PS: If you only have cats and dogs, maybe Animal can have this property ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the dictionary entry by using the [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) operator, which is useful in the case that `dict["cat"]` mistakenly contains a `Dog`. Using `(Cat)dict["cat"]` will throw an exception in that situation.

```
if (dict.ContainsKey("cat"))
{
    Cat dictCat = dict["cat"] as Cat;
    if (dictCat != null)
    {
        // use dictCat
    }
}
```

The dictionary will only consider the values to be `Animal`s, so you will indeed have to cast each time you want to use a member of a derived class.

As mentioned by CodeNotFound in comments, [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression) (introduced in C# 7) is another option if available.

```
if (dict.ContainsKey("cat") && dict["cat"] is Cat cat)
{
    // Dealing with cat :) 
}
```

Comment: It would really help OP I imagine if you explained what the `as` keyword does, and why you are checking if its not null...

Comment: i know that approach. I asked how to achieve that with member, it's my question, not other approach. thank anyway

Comment: You should also add a sample with pattern matching which came with C# 7

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to do

```
dict["cat"] = (Cat) new Cat();
dict["dog"] = (Dog) new Dog();
```

since both `Cat` and `Dog` derive from `Animal`, you can assign them directly

```
dict["cat"] = new Cat();
dict["dog"] = new Dog();
```

Now, to access individual properties use

```
(dict["cat"] as Cat)?.tail
```

which already includes a `null` check via the `?.` operator